# Require expertise in DB Design Guidelines

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I need help with designing certain tables and would like to know if this is the correct approach.

Consider I have a master table named `categories`, which store list of product categories.

And another table `product_categories` which already stores FK with `product` table. Should we also have FK for categories? What is the upside and downside of this. Need DB expertise here.

```
create table product (
  id int,
  name varchar(255)
);

create table categories (
  id int,
  category varchar(255)
);

create table product_categories(
  id int,
  product_id int,
  category varchar(255)
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (id)
);
```

Do we need to use `@ElementCollection` or `@OneToMany` relationship?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should replace the column `category varchar(255)` of `product_categories` by a foreign key to the categories table. Otherwise, you will end up with two different places where the category name is stored, leading to inconsistencies.

> Do we need to use @ElementCollection or @OneToMany relationship?

ElementCollection is for collections of simple or embedded types. Not for associations between entities.

OneToMany is for... one-to-many associations. But you most probably have a many-to-many association here: a product belongs to several categories, and a category contains several products. So you need... ManyToMany.

If you really have a one-to-many association (i.e. a product belongs to a single category, and a category contains several products), then you probably don't want that join table: the product should know the category it belongs to, and you should thus have a category ID foreign key in the product table (and a bidirectional one-to-many association).

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. Product will have multiple categories and categories would be mapped to multiple products. So I assume from it will be `@ManyToMany` from both end. Can I somehow have unidirectional relationship from product to categories and categories doesn't know what products they are mapped to. My concern is categories table would be used by other tables for mapping. Is it good practise to add FK?

Comment: *Can I somehow have unidirectional relationship*: yes. *Is it good practise to add FK*: yes. That's what guarantees that your data is not in an ancoherent state that will make your code crash. It also documents your design.